# Custom WPF/XAML Canvas

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, controls

I'm trying to create and use a custom Canvas. Here is the XAML (MyCanvas.xaml):

```
<Canvas xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:Core="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:Namespace="clr-namespace:MyNamepace" xmlns:Properties="clr-namespace:MyNamepace.Properties" Core:Class="MyNamepace.MyCanvas">
    <Canvas.Resources>
        <Namespace:ImagesConverter Core:Key="ImagesConverter"/>
    </Canvas.Resources>
    <Image Source="{Binding Source={Core:Static Properties:Resources.Background}, Converter={StaticResource ImagesConverter}}" Stretch="Fill"/>
</Canvas>
```

Here is the code declaration (MyCanvas.xaml.cs):

```
public partial class MyCanvas : Canvas
```

When I try to use it like so:

```
<Namespace:MyCanvas Core:Name="Layout" Loaded="OnLoaded">
    <Namespace:MyUserControl Core:Name="Control1" Namespace:MyCanvas.Left="50" MyProperty="50">
        <Namespace:MyCanvas.Top>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MathConverter}" ConverterParameter="(x - y) / 2">
                <Binding ElementName="Layout" Path="ActualHeight"/>
                <Binding Path="ActualHeight" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}"/>
            </MultiBinding>
        </Namespace:MyCanvas.Top>
    </Namespace:MyUserControl>
    <Namespace:MyUserControl Core:Name="Control2" Namespace:MyCanvas.Left="744" Namespace:MyCanvas.Top="42" MyProperty="150"/>
</Namespace:MyCanvas>
```

I get two different errors:

> The property "Content" can only be set once.    ==> Isn't it inheriting Canvas?!?!?!
>
> The member "Top" is not recognized or is not accessible.    ==> Isn't it inheriting Canvas again?!?!?!
>   The member "Left" is not recognized or is not accessible.    ==> Isn't it inheriting Canvas again?!?!?!

**EDIT: this is what I have so far... still getting the "Content" already set error!**

MyCanvas.xaml

```
<Canvas xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:Core="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:Namespace="clr-namespace:MyNamespace" xmlns:Properties="clr-namespace:MyNamespace.Properties" Core:Class="MyNamespace.MyCanvas">
    <Canvas.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding Source={Core:Static Properties:Resources.Background}, Converter={StaticResource ImagesConverter}}" Stretch="Fill"/>
    </Canvas.Background>
    <Canvas.Resources>
        <Namespace:ImagesConverter Core:Key="ImagesConverter"/>
    </Canvas.Resources>
</Canvas>
```

MyCanvas.xaml.cs

```
public class MyCanvas : Canvas
{
    // ...
}
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Namespace:MyCanvas Core:Name="MyCanvas" Loaded="OnLoaded">
    <Namespace:MyUserControl ...
    <Namespace:MyUserControl ...
    <Namespace:MyUserControl ...
</Namespace:MyCanvas>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Left` and `Top` are [attached properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011.aspx). That means that they are not inherited by your class.

You need to change the user control declaration to use `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top` instead:

```
<Namespace:MyUserControl Core:Name="Control2" Canvas.Left="744" Canvas.Top="42" 
                         MyProperty="150"/>
```

The problem with the content is that you set it twice, just like the error message says.

1. In `MyCanvas.xaml` you set it to an `Image`.
2. When using it, you set it to your user controls.

To fix it, you need to add an `ItemsControl` to `MyCanvas` and declare it as the control that represents the content:

```
<Canvas xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:Core="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:Namespace="clr-namespace:MyNamepace" xmlns:Properties="clr-namespace:MyNamepace.Properties" Core:Class="MyNamepace.MyCanvas">
    <Canvas.Resources>
        <Namespace:ImagesConverter Core:Key="ImagesConverter"/>
    </Canvas.Resources>
    <Image Source="{Binding Source={Core:Static Properties:Resources.Background}, Converter={StaticResource ImagesConverter}}" Stretch="Fill"/>
    <ItemsControl Content="{Binding Path=LocalContent, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Namespace:MyCanvas}}}" />
</Canvas>
```

In your class file:

```
[ContentProperty("LocalContent")]
public partial class MyCanvas : Canvas
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty LocalContentProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "LocalContent", 
            typeof(UIElementCollection), 
            typeof(MyCanvas ), 
            new PropertyMetadata(default(UIElementCollection)));
}
```

Comment: Ok... but what about Content problem? It's a damn Canvas after all... multiple children are allowed!

Comment: @Zarathos: Please check update. I haven't tested this, but it should work something like that.

Comment: What is the canvas sitting in? Is it just inside the window? Or inside of another grid/canvas? Canvas isn't a content control, so you shouldn't get an error about content, because it doesn't have a content property. The canvas' container is probably a content control holding two items.

Comment: @sircodesalot: That's not correct. `Canvas` *is* a content control and it has a content property named `Children`. It inherits that from `Panel`.

Comment: Panel != Content Control. See: http://miteshsureja.blogspot.com/2011/06/wpf-class-hierarchy.html

Comment: @sircodesalot: How would you define a content control? My definition is: Everything that holds content. And that is true for all controls.

Comment: I see what you're getting at, but I don't fully agree. There are three main branches of controls. Content Controls (like button or label), Panels (like grid and canvas), and Items Controls (like list boxes). They are what they are because of their place in the hierarchy. IE, all of those are UIElements, because they all inherit from UIElement, but a Canvas is not a Content Control, because it does not inherit from Content Control. It's impossible to get a 'content error' from a canvas, because it has no content property (which comes from content control).

Comment: @sircodesalot: Aha. Nevertheless, the comment of yours I originally replied is still wrong. The content of the Canvas is what is "inside" its tag `<Canvas> this is the content </Canvas>`. That content is mapped to a specific property on the Canvas class. Which property that is is determined by the `ContentPropertyAttribute`. Thus, the error message the OP is getting is in fact coming from the `Canvas` and additionally makes sense - who would have thought?

Comment: Is there an easier way to implement a background to a Canvas? Like... uhm... using Background property instead of that ItemsControl?

Answer (score 4):

Adding to Daniel's answer, you have to understand that WPF introduces a concept called 'Dependency Properties' and 'Dependency Objects'. In short, just as Objects in C# can have properties, Dependency Objects in WPF can have dependency properties. The way this works is a bit different though that the c# method.

For dependency properties (such as attached properties), WPF manages a seperate table with records indicating which objects have which properties. Which in other words, means it's possible for any object to have any property, WPF just adds a record to the table giving said object said property. So for example, Canvas.Left, while being *defined* by Canvas, can be implemented by any control. WPF simply inserts a record into the dependency table, and voila now your image has Canvas.Left / Canvas.Top properties. This means a much smaller memory footprint, because object *opt into* having a property (when the record is added), rather than having a property just because it derives from a certain class.

The way this works programatically, is you use DependencyObject.SetValue / GetValue (all WPF objects derive from DependencyObject see: http://miteshsureja.blogspot.com/2011/06/wpf-class-hierarchy.html - in fact, memorize this graph because it will help you better to understand how WPF works under the hood), and this adds / reads from a record to the aforementioned table. When you define a dependency property, you your c# accessors should really redirect to these methods, because WPF (and not the object itself) should be managing these values (this is how WPF is able to do data-binding and what not, because it manages the values and just shifts them to other objects as neccesasry). For an example of creating a dependency property, see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914.aspx . The concept behind dependency properties is very simple, but you have to at least be aware of it in order to understand a lot of WPFs functionality.

Comment: `Canvas.Left` is an attached property, not a dependency property.

Comment: Right, but an attached property *IS-A* dependency property. You just register them different ways: DependencyProperty.Register (regular) vs. DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached (for attached)

Comment: Indeed. And this distinction is important.